# Declaring an Array and altering its contents

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing test code to explore properties of an Array.
Why does this work

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] testing={1,2,3};
    for(int i = 0;i<testing.length;i++){
        System.out.println(testing[i]);
    }
}
```

and why doesn't this work?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] testing= new int[3];
    testing = {1,2,3};
    for(int i = 0;i<testing.length;i++){
        System.out.println(testing[i]);
    }
}
```

What is it about Array that prevents this from being valid?

Comment: It was just a language design decision.  In truth, I can't think of a technical reason why it shouldn't have been allowed in an assignment.  Allowing it as a method parameter could conceivably cause headaches for overload resolution, though.

Answer (score 9):

Because the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) says so

> **An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3,
>   §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create
>   an array and provide some initial values.**

So you can either use it as you are already doing

```
int[] testing = {1,2,3};
```

or as part of an array creation expression

```
testing = new int[]{1,2,3};
```